# DiscordJS 14 Voice works on Windows but not Linux

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

Discord.js V14 voice works on windows but as soon as I run it through an Ubuntu server, it doesn't work. I have install all dependencies on both platforms. Whenever I try to play audio through the Ubuntu server it gets the bot to join the voice channel, but no sound is played. I have narrowed it down to some sort of playback issue with FFMpeg, and I have tried using opus. Here is the Dependency report generated on the ubuntu server:

> Core Dependencies
>
> - @discordjs/voice: 0.16.1
> - prism-media: 1.3.5
>   Opus Libraries
> - @discordjs/opus: 0.9.0
> - opusscript: not found
>   Encryption Libraries
> - sodium-native: 4.0.4
> - sodium: not found
> - libsodium-wrappers: 0.7.13
> - tweetnacl: not found
>   FFmpeg
> - version: 6.0-static
> - libopus: yes

Here is the file it is using to run the music. There are no errors in the output:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const {
  AudioPlayerStatus,
  createAudioPlayer,
  createAudioResource,
  joinVoiceChannel,
  StreamType,
} = require("@discordjs/voice");
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("play")
    .setDescription("Plays a song.")
    .addAttachmentOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("song")
        .setDescription("The song to play.")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),

  async execute(interaction) {
    await interaction.reply({ content: "Preparing song...", ephemeral: true });
    const attachment = interaction.options.getAttachment("song");
    const channel = interaction.member.voice.channel;
    if (!channel)
      return await interaction.editReply({
        content: "Join a voice channel!",
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: channel.id,
      guildId: channel.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    console.log(attachment.url);
    const resource = createAudioResource(attachment.url, {
      inputType: StreamType.Opus,
    });
    player.play(resource);
    connection.subscribe(player);
    await interaction.editReply({
      content: `Playing ${attachment.name}!`,
      ephemeral: true,
    });
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
      console.log("destroy");
      connection.destroy();
    });
  },
};
```